# Two quick eigenvalues & complex numbers questions

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, complex-numbers

**A)** For a vector $v\in\mathbb{C^n}$, is $Im(-v)=Im(\overline{v})$ ?

($Im(v)$denoting the imaginary part of the vector $v$)

My understanding: since every row of the vector is a complex number (say $z=a+bi$), then for every row:

$Im(-z)=Im(-a-bi)=-b=Im(a-bi)=Im(\overline{z})$

**B)** If $Av=\lambda v$ for some $\lambda\in\mathbb{C}$ (where $A$ is a matrix representing some linear transformation), is then $A(Re(v))=\lambda Re(v)$ and $A(Im(v))=\lambda Im(v)$?

<strike>My understanding: Once again, looking at rows of the vector, since the right hand side is its multiple (by $\lambda$), for every row of $v$: $\lambda(a+bi)=\lambda a+ \lambda bi$. Thus both real and imaginary parts are its multiples (by $\lambda$) after the transformation.</strike>

**edit**: As pointed out in the comments, **B** is generally not true. Additional question then: is there something we **can** say about the imaginary and real parts multiplied by the matrix A?

Thanks!

Comment: Be careful for B: $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}$ you argument works only if $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Ha! That's exactly why I wanted to ask this, I knew I'd miss something. Thanks.

Comment: Well you have $\lambda(a+bi)=(\Re \lambda + i \Im \lambda)(a+bi) = (a\Re \lambda-b \Im \lambda)+i(b\Re \lambda + a \Im \lambda)$

Comment: For complex vector spaces, the operations of taking complex conjugate and/or real/imaginary parts are usually **not defined**. You can obviously define them in $\Bbb C^n$, but they won't be the same operation after a change of basis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $v$ is a eigenvector corresponding to $\lambda$ then $v$ is answer of the system $[A-\lambda ]v=0$. There is no any guarantee that the real part of $V$ is an answer too.

Suppose $v=[a_{i}+ib_{i}]_{i=0,\ldots,n}$

$ [A−\lambda][a_i +ib_i ]_{i=1,\ldots,n} =[A−\lambda][a_i ]_{i=1,\ldots,n} +[A−\lambda][ib_i ]_{i=1,\ldots,n =0}$. It will happen if

(then real of $V$ will be eigenvector corresponding to $\lambda$) if $[A−\lambda][a_i ]_{i=1,\ldots,n =0}$ and

$[A−\lambda] [ib_{i}]_{i=1,\ldots,n}=0$

Also for image of $v$ this is satisfied.